# How can I make VSC use the same venv everytime?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running MAC OS have my venv in my root folder of my project

/root/venv but VSC does not seem to detect it. Everytime i open the project i have to source the venv

source venv/bin/activate

I want VSC to just auto use this everytime I open the project. I've tried setting the python interpreter to be the one in the venv but that does not seem to activate the venv.

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code, the python virtual environment it recognizes is as shown in the following figure: (For example: the virtual environment ".env01" is stored in the project root directory, and it contains the required related files and folders.)

[image]

It is recommended that you create a new virtual environment in VS Code (`python3 -m venv .ven_name`). After selecting and using this environment, VS Code will automatically display and use this environment, and use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment.

Reference: [virtual environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried this, here is my steps (inside VSC)

python3 -m venv .test  
source .test/bin/activate  
restart VSC  
no environment is set when launching  

there is no prompt as showed in your reference.

Comment: @Kinder9211 -After using the command "python3 -m venv .test" or "python -m venv .test", does VS Code display a pop-up box indicating that the virtual environment is successfully created?

Comment: it does not. I've tried restarting everything but the prompt does not show. I only have the recommended Python plugin from Microsoft.

Comment: @Kinder9211  -To create a virtual environment in VS Code, please make sure that python is available and the "Python" extension in VSCode is available, and then use the command "python -m venv .env_name" in the VS Code terminal to create a virtual environment, and wait for it to be created. Please refer to [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)